# How do I convert a JSON serialized object into a JS object, so I can access its properties?

Tags: javascript, json, web-services

In my JavaScript I want to access the properties of a JSON serialized object that was produced via a .NET web service.  How do I deserialize the JSON data into an object that I can manipulate in JavaScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `json2.js` from http://json.org -- it provides a `JSON` object on the global object that provides a `parse` function.  It has the added advantage of being the basis for the ES3.1 specification of JSON, and will use a native implementation of JSON if possible.  This means that you can parse a json serialised object with:

```
object = JSON.parse(string)
```

Because of the way it is implemented this means if you page is viewed in a browser that supports JSON (eg. Safari 4, Firefox 3.5, even IE8) you will get a fast and *secure* parser automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery and do the web service call via [getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON)

Or you could use the [official json parser](http://www.json.org/json.js).

Comment: I'm using Dojo currently.  Would you know of an equivalent function in Dojo's library?

Comment: looks like there's a dojo.fromJson function that'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Dojo.json](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-porting-guide-0-4-x-0-9/dojo-json) package. It contains toJson() and fromJson() functions.

You shouldn't use eval() unless you **really** trust your data provider. eval() can evaluate functions and call them, can raise random exceptions etc. Use libraries and you'll be on the safer side.

**EDIT::**

**crescentfresh** pointed out that *dojo.fromJson()* is just a wrapper for *eval()*. That's true, sadly, but even at [JSON.org](http://json.org/js.html) they say that *eval()* can be a security issue, and they should know what they're talking about :)

You can use external JSON parser (see: [code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval](http://code.google.com/p/json-sans-eval) for example), or just use *dojo.fromJson()* and hope they'll improve it in next version

Comment: Here is the entire implementation of `"dojo.fromJson"`: `function(s){return eval("(" + s + ")")}`. See for yourself: http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/tags/release-1.3.2/dojo/_base/json.js

Comment: No reason to include yet another library to use 1 or 2 methods; just do like olliej says below and go to json.org and get json2.js.